# Ignore a file in git but have it downloaded when the project is cloned

Tags: git, ignore, gitignore, pull, git-clone

I have a file that suffers modification every time I run my project. Thus, I don't want git to track it and so I add it to my .gitignore file.

However, I do wish for the file to be pulled when cloning the project.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot ignore a file, not track it and expect it to be available in clone.

What you can do is, add the file to the repo, run `git update-index --assume-unchanged` so that git "ignores" the changes to it and then you will have the file in clone.

Comment: I thought so, but it didn't hurt to ask :)
Btw, that command must be run at every commit or just once works just fine?